# magento - How to create page with pagination in magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to add Mostviewed located here:

```
App/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Mostviewed.php
```

I have added the following code:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
   public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addViewsCount();
        $collection->getSelect()->joinInner(array('e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_'.$storeId), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');
        $this->setProductCollection($collection);
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

I'm added `echo $this->getToolbarHtml()` located here:

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/mostviewedlist.phtml
```

Can't show the pagination in `mostviewedlist.phtml.`

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Block should be like this:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addViewsCount();
        $collection->getSelect()->joinInner(array('e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_'.$storeId), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');
        $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'mostview.pager')
                      ->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getProductCollection()->load();

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
}
```

Your template should be like this:

```
<?php $_collection = $this->getProductCollection(); ?>

<!-- top pagination -->
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>

<?php if($_collection->getSize()): ?>
    ...
    <?php foreach ($_collection as $_item): ?>
       ...
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif ?>

<!-- bottom pagination -->
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
```

If you want to display toolbar. Your block should be like this:
(NOTE: I didn't test this code)

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addViewsCount();
        $collection->getSelect()->joinInner(array('e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_'.$storeId), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');
        $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $toolbar = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar', microtime())
            ->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', microtime());
        $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->getProductCollection()->load();

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code,it's working well.I want to show dropdown page like 5 10 15 20...,how to change the number.And other one,how to add sort by?

Comment: I used the second method.I cliked sort by but not to change.I think that there are something wrong with `public function __construct()`.Can you help me?